# returning a value from a nested loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, sorting

hey guys so i am writing a program to sort a list of words alphabetically based upon my limited programming knowledge, i know there are high level functions that make it easier but i am trying to do it the hard way, anyway, i decided i would do it by adding together the alphabetical values of each character in the string and then putting them into a sorted string array based upon least to greatest value and string length, as part of this i am writing a function that will add the letters values together via a loop... here is my source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int ABReturn_value(string a);
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    cout<<ABReturn_value("a")<<endl;
    return 0;
}
int ABReturn_value(string a){
    //declare an internal character array containing the alphabet
    char alphabet[2][26] = {{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'},{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'}};
    //variable to hold the acrued value
    int value=0;
    //look through the provided string's characters and acrue the value based on which address in the refernece array the letter corresponds to
     for(unsigned int x = 0;x<=(a.size())-1;x++)
        for(int y=0;y<=26-1;y++){
            if(a[x]==alphabet[1][y]||a[x]==alphabet[2][y]){
                value+=y;
            }
        }
     return value;
}
```

the problem im running into is based on this test input of the character a i am expecting the function to return me a value of 1 but it is instead returning 40,ive been staring at it and cant seem to figure out what i did wrong so maybe theres something im missing? thanks in advance!

Comment: `alphabet[1]` should be `alphabet[0]` and `alphabet[2]` should be `alphabet[1]`

Comment: The "hard way" in C++ would effectively be C code. Also realize that `char`s are integers, and can be directly compared. For example, `'c' > 'a'`.

Comment: `y<=26-1` is more conventionally, and concisely, written as `y < 26`.

Comment: @immibis THAT DID IT OMG HOW DID I NOT NOTICE THAT ITS SO OBVIOUS thanks mate!

Comment: @Kupiakos thanks for the tip, i realise that but wasnt sure if i could trust the ascii values to provide the results i was looking for

Comment: If you add the values of the letters together, how will you sort "act" before "cat"?

Comment: @AlanStokes good point, ive been out of this( programming) for so long im glad to have gotten help here, makes me feel like i can make real progress

Comment: @AlanStokes hmm another thing i had not considered... i was going to take the word lengths into account for cases where higher valued letters resulted in equal values but i really dont know how to curb that one... is my overall approach flawed?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it is. Luckily it is already possible to compare two `std::string` objects directly, so reducing them to a single number is unnecessary.

Comment: change this line: `if(a[x]==alphabet[1][y]||a[x]==alphabet[2][y])` to `if(a[x]==alphabet[0][y]||a[x]==alphabet[1][y])` and it "works" arrays in C++ start at 0 index.

Comment: @AlanStokes ok thats good to know, as for my overall goal , since my current approach is obviously not going to yield what i am aiming for, do you (or anyone else) have any advice on how i may better go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@immibis has answered this, could you tag it as answered please?

> alphabet[1] should be alphabet[0] and alphabet[2] should be alphabet[1] – immibis